# Legacy Java code use of com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider()

Tags: java, ssl, provider, legacy

I am working with some code from back in 2003. There is a reference to the following class:

```
new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider()
```

It is causing an error:

`Access restriction: The type Provider is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar`

Does anyone have any suggestions for a suitable alternative to using this class?

Comment: I don't know that class, but I can read 'ssl'. If that's Secure Socket Layer, please consider [javax.net.ssl.*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/package-summary.html)

Comment: There's rarely any reason to instantiate the provider manually like this. What's the code around?

Answer (score 10):

Throw that line of code away. Also throw away any reference to the `com.sun.net.ssl` package and its sub-packages: fix the imports so they refer to the classes in `javax.net.ssl.`

This is pre-JDK 1.4 code, from the days when JSSE was a separate download.

Comment: What is the option if this is called by a third party lib, specifically in my case, tibcrypt?

Answer (score 8):

Most of the time, you don't actually need to create or get hold of a provider instance yourself. As the [Oracle Providers documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) says:

> General purpose applications SHOULD NOT request cryptographic services
>   from specific providers. That is:
>
> ```
> getInstance("...", "SunJCE");  // not recommended
>     vs.
> getInstance("...");            // recommended
> ```

In addition, wherever there's an overloaded parameter for the provider, it tends to take either a string or an instance, but the string (name) would probably be more common. (Passing an instance can be useful sometimes, e.g. for some PKCS#11 configurations, but it's unusual.)

The [JCA documentation about Providers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Provider) should be useful.

If you really want to get hold of a specific instance, you can use `Security.getProvider(name)`. You'll find the appropriate names in the providers documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn this into a warning or non-event in Eclipse preferences `Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings->Deprecated and restricted API`.  Note, as others have said, this not the best practice and should be avoided when you have alternatives.

Comment: Yes, you can, but you generally should not, at least not globally.

Comment: why vote this down?  it is a viable way of dealing with legacy code

Comment: As a general recommendation I find it dangerous. As a temporary solution it can be ok. I like your edit and removed the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I used `import com.sun.security.sasl.Provider;` in OPEN JDK 21 and works.