# package com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl is not visible

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I'm new to java and I was trying to build an echo server and a client using **SSL SOCKETS**. Then I compile the server code first. but the command prompt gave me the following error.**package com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl is not visible**. And there's another message within brackets..**package com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl is declared in module java.base,which does not export it** Can somebody please help me with this?? Or provide me an alternative code. But please don't make it complex..I'm just a beginner to this.

server code

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
import java.security.Security;
import com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider;

public class Server 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //The Port number through which this server will accept client connections
        int port = 9000;
        /*Adding the JSSE (Java Secure Socket Extension) provider which provides SSL and TLS protocols
        and includes functionality for data encryption, server authentication, message integrity, 
        and optional client authentication.*/
        Security.addProvider(new Provider());
        //specifing the keystore file which contains the certificate/public key and the private key
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","myKeyStore.jks");
        //specifing the password of the keystore file
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","123456");
        //This optional and it is just to show the dump of the details of the handshake process 
        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","all");
        try
        {
            //SSLServerSocketFactory establishes the ssl context and and creates SSLServerSocket 
            SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
            //Create SSLServerSocket using SSLServerSocketFactory established ssl context
            SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket)sslServerSocketfactory.createServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Echo Server Started & Ready to accept Client Connection");
            //Wait for the SSL client to connect to this server
            SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket)sslServerSocket.accept();
            //Create InputStream to recive messages send by the client
            DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(sslSocket.getInputStream());
            //Create OutputStream to send message to client
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(sslSocket.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeUTF("Hello Client, Say Something!");
            //Keep sending the client the message you recive unless he sends the word "close"
            while(true)
            {
                String recivedMessage = inputStream.readUTF();
                System.out.println("Client Said : " + recivedMessage);
                if(recivedMessage.equals("close"))
                {
                    outputStream.writeUTF("Bye");
                    outputStream.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    sslSocket.close();
                    sslServerSocket.close();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    outputStream.writeUTF("You Said : "+recivedMessage);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Error Happened : "+ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Client code

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.security.Security;
import com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider;

public class Client
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //The Port number through which the server will accept this clients connection
        int serverPort = 9000;
        //The Server Address
        String serverName = "192.168.5.1";
        /*Adding the JSSE (Java Secure Socket Extension) provider which provides SSL and TLS protocols
        and includes functionality for data encryption, server authentication, message integrity, 
        and optional client authentication.*/
        Security.addProvider(new Provider());
        //specifing the trustStore file which contains the certificate & public of the server
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","myTrustStore.jts");
        //specifing the password of the trustStore file
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","123456");
        //This optional and it is just to show the dump of the details of the handshake process 
        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","all");
        try
        {
            //SSLSSocketFactory establishes the ssl context and and creates SSLSocket 
            SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            //Create SSLSocket using SSLServerFactory already established ssl context and connect to server
            SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket)sslsocketfactory.createSocket(serverName,serverPort);
            //Create OutputStream to send message to server
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(sslSocket.getOutputStream());
            //Create InputStream to read messages send by the server
            DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(sslSocket.getInputStream());
            //read the first message send by the server after being connected
            System.out.println(inputStream.readUTF());
            //Keep sending sending the server the message entered by the client unless the it is "close"
            while (true)
            {
                System.out.println("Write a Message : ");
                String messageToSend = System.console().readLine();
                outputStream.writeUTF(messageToSend);
                System.err.println(inputStream.readUTF());
                if(messageToSend.equals("close"))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Error Happened : "+ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Java 9+? You should use the `--add-exports` option

Comment: This sample code looks very old to me. SSL/TLS functionality is always available in java without adding any provider ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13160829/150978) indicates that it was already legacy 8 years ago...). Hence you should just remove the line with `addProvider` and the correspondent import.

Comment: I removed those parts. then i could compile the program. But when I execute it, command prompt keeps generating logs without stopping..

Comment: Remove this statement: `Security.addProvider(new Provider());`

Comment: I did that. I could compile the program. but I can't execute it.command prompt is showing logs without stopping when I execute the program.